# (EXCEL VBA) How to remove commas and spaces from txt output?

Tags: excel, vba, space

I have an excel file that looks like this:

**3001  T81 90300010    001**

**3001  T81 90300011    001**

and the issue is that some of the numbers are numbers stored as txt.

Also there are strings: "T81"

I need the outputted txt file to look like this:

**3001T8190300010001**

No Spaces, quotes, etc.

I was able to run this script to do most of the legwork:

```
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, I As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\test_data_output.txt"
Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

For I = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

cellValue = rng.Cells(I, j).Value

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue
Else
    Write #1, cellValue,
End If

    Next j
Next I

Close #1
```

Now its output is not quite perfect:

**3001,"T81",90300010,"001"**

**3001,"T81","90300011","001"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where you set cellValue, just keep adding the strings together (converting value to strings):

```
cellValue = cellValue + Cstr(rng.Cells(I, j).Value)
```

Then between your next j and next I, reset cellValue:

```
    Next j
    cellValue = ""
Next I
```

Comment: This almost worked... yielded this:

"3001","3001T81","3001T8190300011","3001T8190300011001"

Comment: I used Print! that seems to solve all issues. Also changed the loop to write the last cellbyValue! Thanks!

Comment: Yea, that was my mistake.  I thought you were only printing a specific one with your IF statement, just realized the ELSE would get it anyway.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim v as Variant

v = rng.Value

For i = LBound(v,1) to UBound(v,1)
    Write #1, Replace(Replace(Join(WorksheetFunction.Index(v,i,0),""),",","")," ","")
Next
```

Comment: Where in the code should this fit? Replacing the If EndIf part?

Comment: It should replace your For loops.

Comment: I used a similar method actually! Now that I look back (The code and problem changed a lot past couple of days. Thanks!